# Left with a piece after changing the tire [PICTURE]

Tags: tires, mercedes-benz, spare-tire

Someone put replace the front left tire with the spare one and left this outside :O What is this? It seems worn out a bit. Should I worry?

[image]
[image]

Car: Mercedes  09 ML350

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture what material that's made of, is it plastic, metal or some combination?

Comment: @GdD The outside is plastic, but no too light.

Comment: Are you positive that came from your car?

Comment: Please, edit your answer, using proper grammar, for sentence structure.

Comment: I understand, you're trying to identify the piece here. But I can't comprehend to full extent what you went through. Share all 6 sides of that part as images.

Comment: @DavidLively I am.

Comment: @NumairAidroos Due to my rank, I cannot add more than 2 links

Comment: Add photos to Facebook, Google plus, Instagram anf send us the link or just email us at Numair@zezan.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "jack pad" which is used in elevating the car when changing tire or other mechanical inspections. It's attached under the car (somewhere around the side edge of the chassis).

https://www.google.com/search?q=jack+pad+mercedes+2009+ml350&oq=jack+pad+mercedes+2009+ml350&aqs=chrome..69i57.238j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8